# How to subset the fonts used in a pdf? (with iTextSharp)

Tags: pdf, fonts, itext, subset

I generated a pdf report with ASP.NET + iTextSharp.
I used several types of fonts in it, each font applied to a word or 2 for art reasons.
So the file is large.

How can I only embed the fonts I actually used? Just like what we do with MS Office Options.

MS Office Word 2007 is like this:
"Embed fonts in the file:
Embed only the characters used in the document(best for reducing file size)
Do not embed common system fonts"

OR I can also accept another kind of solution.
Flatten the whole page to a high-resolution picture.
If the programming is convenient, I actually prefer this solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us what code you are using to create the fonts that are embedding? If you use `BaseFont.IDENTITY_H` for the encoding it should subset the font for you automatically. @mark-storer talks about font embedding a little more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525170/gdicharset-itextsharp/4541217#4541217

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating your `BaseFont` instance with embedding enabled, you need to call `myBaseFont.setSubset(true)`.  Note that with the encoding "Identity-H" (AKA `BaseFont.IDENTITY_H`), this happens automatically:

```
// find all fonts in the usual places across multiple OSs.
// This can be pretty slow if you have a large number fonts, or the fonts
// themselves are Really Big (ArialUnicodeMS: 23mb).
FontFactory.registerDirectories();

// here's one way to do it, using identity-h forces subsetting
Font myFontSubset1 = FontFactory.getFont(fontName1, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H);

// here's another, explicitly enable subsetting for the underlying BaseFont.
Font myFontSubset2 = FontFactory.getFont(fontName2, FontFactory.defaultEncoding, true);
myFontSubset2.getBaseFont().setSubset(true);

//or you can create the BaseFont yourself, with automagic subsetting
BaseFont myFontSubset3 = BaseFont.createFont(fontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H);

// or create it with some other encoding, and enable subsetting.
BaseFont myFontSubset4 = BaseFont.createFont(fontPath, BaseFont.WINANSI, true);
myFontSubset4.setSubset(true);
```

Note that this is all Java.  In C# the first letter of function names are capitalized and `setX(newX)` and `getX()` become properties.

Comment: `public static BaseFont bfKaiti = BaseFont.CreateFont(rptResource + "simkai.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);`
Is that what you said about BaseFont.IDENTITY_H?

Comment: So the large size of the pdf file is not due to fonts? Maybe I asked the wrong question. But thanks very much! At least we exclude one reason.

Comment: Acrobat Pro has a "PDF Size Audit" feature you can run on a PDF to see what exactly is taking up all that space.  You can download a free trial.  ;)

Comment: That was the only documentation of BaseFont.setSubset() I could find online (dramatic...). Thank you.